# What is the difference between these three alternative ways to write Ruby regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match the path "/". I've tried the following alternatives, and the first two do match, but I don't know why the third doesn't:

```
/\A\/\z/.match("/")                # <MatchData "/">
"/\A\/\z/".match("/")              # <MatchData "/">
Regexp.new("/\A\/\z/").match("/")  # nil
```

What's going on here? Why are they different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first snippet is the only correct one.

The second example is... misleading. That string literal `"/\A\/\z/"` is, obviously, not a regex. It's a string. Strings have [#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-match) method which converts its argument to a regexp (if not already one) and match against it. So, in this example, it's `'/'` that is the regular expression, and it matches a forward slash found in the other string.

The third line is completely broken: don't need the surrounding slashes there, they are part of regex literal, which you didn't use. Also use single quoted strings, not double quoted (which try to interpret escape sequences like `\A`)

```
Regexp.new('\A/\z').match("/") # => #<MatchData "/">
```

And, of course, none of the above is needed if you just want to check if a string consists of only one forward slash. Just use the equality check in this case.

```
s == '/'
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that I should never use strings in constructing regular expressions in Ruby? Just use the forward slashes as in: Regexp.new(/\A\/\z/).match("/"). Is this the best way?

Comment: Use the literal: `/\A\/\z/`, it is already a fully functional regexp object, no need for `Regexp.new`.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: `r = Regexp.new("\\A/\\z") #=> /\A\/\z/; r.match("/") #=> #<MatchData "/">`.